# requestAnimationFrame gives the wrong timestamp when showing a confirm dialog (Chromium?)

Tags: javascript, animation, chromium

I have a simple animation, which is done using `requestAnimationFrame` (for demo purposes adapted from [the example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)). If before the animation I show a `confirm` dialog, the timestamp received by the animation function is wrong. The difference between the first and second timestamps is equal to the time from the moment the `confirm` message was shown, until the "OK" button was clicked. This behaviour (bug?) is visible in Chrome and Opera (both running Chromium). Firefox and Internet Explorer 11 run as expected. Check [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qtj467n0/2/) or the example below.

```js
const cache = {
  start: null,
  target: null
};

function animate(timestamp) {
  console.log(timestamp);
  if (cache.start === null) {
    cache.start = timestamp;
  }
  var progress = timestamp - cache.start;
  cache.target.style.left = Math.min(progress / 10, 100) + 'px';
  if (progress < 1000) {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  } else {
    cache.target.style.left = 0;
    cache.start = null;
  }
}

(function() {
  const target = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
  cache.target = target;
  const cb = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];

  const btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (cb.checked) {
      if (confirm("Just click 'OK' to start the animation, ok?")) {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      }
    } else {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
  })
})();
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
}

button {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Start</button>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" />use "confirm"</label>
<div>

</div>
```

Open the console to see the received timestamps. The animation is set to run for 2 seconds. When showing the `confirm` dialog, if the "OK" button gets clicked faster than 2 seconds, the animation runs for the "remaining" time. If the time needed to click the "OK" button is longer than the time animation time, the element will not be animated and there will be 2 values (timestamps) sent to the console; the difference of these 2 values is the time needed to click the "OK" button.

I assume that this is a bug in Chromium. Is there a workaround for this (still animating with `requestAnimationFrame`, not trough CSS)? I couldn't find anything regarding this in their tracker. Does anybody have additional info on this?

Comment: In general I'd recommend you avoid `confirm`/`alert` type of boxes as they block the thread and thus pause the timers.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides I know. I also remember that they're trying the remove them completely. But in this example, this is not relevant. The thread is blocked and resumed before the animation is started. The weird part is the difference between two consecutive animation frame timestamps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to say, I found this very interesting.

After spending to much time on it I may have found a workaround for you. You can see that here. https://jsfiddle.net/qtj467n0/13/

The basic gist of it is, I replaced the `DOMHighResTimeStamp` that `requestAnimationFrame` provides with `performance.now()` which also returns a `DOMHighResTimeStamp`.

```js
const cache = {
  start: null,
  target: null,
  time: 2000
};

function animate(timestamp) {
  console.log(timestamp);
  if (cache.start === null) {
    cache.start = timestamp;
  }
  var progress = timestamp - cache.start;
  cache.target.style.left = Math.min(progress / 10, cache.time / 10) + 'px';
  if (progress < cache.time) {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  } else {
    cache.target.style.left = 0;
    cache.start = null;
  }
}

const render = () => {

  requestAnimationFrame((timestamp) => {

    const performanceNow = performance.now();

    animate(performanceNow)
  });
}

(function() {
  const target = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
  cache.target = target;
  const cb = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];


  const btn = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
  btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (cb.checked) {
      const confirmed = confirm("Just click 'OK' to start the animation, ok?");
      if (confirmed) {
        render();
      }
    } else {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
  })
})();
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
}

button {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Start</button>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" />use "confirm"</label>
<div>

</div>
```

Comment: Nicely done! It's interesting that the values from `performance.now()` and `requestAnimationFrame` are different. In my opinion, this further confirms that it's a bug.

Comment: @AndreiV Yes, I have to agree. Are you going to report it?

Comment: Good luck, you seem hesitant? Interested to know how the report procedure works. Have to read up on it when I have the time.

Comment: I think it needs a lot more time than writing a SO question. That means, I just have to find the time...